# How do I make a gallery where I can hover or a video OR image thumbnail and have a larger image appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to create an image gallery like this. https://angel.co/payward-kraken

Main points: 
 1. It has a larger image which I want to swap out for what's in the thumbnails when I hover over them.
 2. I want to the first "larger image" to be a video. 
 3. I want the caption to change with each image switch.

I have been able to figure out how to make a list of thumbnails that I can hover over and change a larger image. I also asked a previous question and got a great answer on how to do it to have a video swap in. The problem I'm stuck in is how to have the captions change  and how to have the video be the first thing that appears.

This is what I've been working off of..

```
HTML 
<div id="imgDetail">
 <video  width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/Traackr.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/traackr2.png" id="bigImg" />
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing2.png"  class="thumb" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing3.png" class="thumb" />
   </li>
    <li ><img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing4.png" class="thumb   video" /></li>
   <!--- Etc--->
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imgDetail video
{
  display:none;
 }

ul, ol {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#imgDetail li img').not(".video").hover(function(){
    $('#imgDetail video').hide();
    $('#bigImg').show();        
    $('#bigImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});

$('#imgDetail li img.video').hover(function(){
    $('#bigImg').hide();
    $('#imgDetail video').show();        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xb25p/.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the changing of captions, you can store the the captions as `data` attributes on the elements themselves. For example, you can do this:

```
<img src="http://theinfluence.co/assets/img/ebuzzing1.png" class="thumb" data-caption="My caption here"/>
```

In HTML5, data attributes act as "hidden input" fields, where you can actually store and access data without it being viewable to the user. You can then access the caption by using jQuery's `.data()` method in your hover function like so:

```
$('#imgDetail li img.video').hover(function(){
    var caption = $(this).data('caption');
    // Use your caption here
    $('#bigImg').hide();
    $('#imgDetail video').show();        
});
```

For the caption element itself, I suggest using HTML5's built-in feature for this, by using a figure:

```
<figure id="myFigure">
    <img src='image.jpg' />
    <figcaption>Caption here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

If you do that, you can simply change the caption by the following jQuery:

```
$('#imgDetail li img.video').hover(function(){
    var caption = $(this).data('caption');
    $('#myFigure > figcaption').text(caption);        

    $('#bigImg').hide();
    $('#imgDetail video').show();        
});
```

To make the video first, all you really have to do is start the "bigImg" element as hidden. You can do this by adding this line in its CSS rules:

```
#bigImg {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is good. Thanks! should I add the figure id and figcaption to each <li> image? 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure id="myFigure">
             <img src="assets/img/contentdj1.png" class="thumb" data-caption="Caption 1"/>
              <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
             </figure>

Comment: Nope, no need to do that. Just surround your 'bigImg' element with a figure element, adding a "figcaption" element after the image.